# Localization is an idempotent A-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

One of my homework problems asks us to prove that let $S$ be a subset of a ring $A$, the localization $A[S^{-1}]$ is an idempotent $A$-algebra. I don't remember my instructor defining an "idempotent $A$-algebra" in class. The assignment is due soon so I probably won't have time to ask him. Could anyone help clarify what is an idempotent $A$-algebra?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a standard name. My first guess is that this could mean that the multiplication map $S^{-1}A \otimes_A S^{-1} A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: This is definitely not standard terminology.